# Process promise returned data using decorator or interceptor in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript, decorator, interceptor, angular-promise

I have a service that does an http request to save some data. When the data comes from the backend I am doing some manipulation on the data and then return it so that controllers can use them. Something like:

```
    public savePerson = (person: Model.IPerson): ng.IPromise<Model.IMiniPerson> => {
        return this.api.persons.save({}, person).then((savedPerson) => {
            this.enrichWithLookups(savedPerson);
            var miniPerson = new Model.MiniPerson();
            angular.extend(miniPerson, savedPerson);
            miniPerson.afterLoad();
            this.persons.unshift(miniPerson);
            this.notifyOfChanges();
            return miniPerson;
        });
    }
```

In order to clean up the code a bit and make it more testable I wanted to remove the private manipulation functions into decorating/intercepting services. Problem is I do not know how to hook on the promise data before the success function is executed and after it is returned.

For example enrichWithLookups must be applied first just after the data arrives and not after the miniPerson is returned.

Comment: you use syntax like : `api.then(miniPersonHook).then(enrichWithLookups)` basically promise chains

Answer (score 0):

you can create a local promise and call the "resolve" method when you have completed your operations on the http response. Look at the code down here:

```
public savePerson = (person: Model.IPerson): ng.IPromise<Model.IMiniPerson> => {
        var waiter = $q.defer();

        this.api.persons.save({}, person).then((savedPerson) => {
            this.enrichWithLookups(savedPerson);
            var miniPerson = new Model.MiniPerson();
            angular.extend(miniPerson, savedPerson);
            miniPerson.afterLoad();
            this.persons.unshift(miniPerson);
            this.notifyOfChanges();
            waiter.resolve(miniPerson);
        });

        return waiter.promise;
    }
```

I've wrote the code directly with angularjs, but I think that you can easily adapt it to fit your needs.

Bye.

Comment: Problem is that success already has the miniPerson resolved in it and not the original data. Inside the decorator I would get a promise but the promise would first be resolved inside the service and afterwards on the decorating service.

Comment: Ok I get what you mean now, but this involves changing the original service to use $q to wrap the original promise. It is definitely one way of doing it, I was just hoping for a cleaner way, where the original service would not have to be altered.

Comment: I understand what you mean; you have two ways: put this logic in the service, as I said before, or put the check logic in the controller; this last means that you need to put  something that wait for data visualization until it understand that the decorator has accomplished its work.

Comment: Unfortunately the second option is not an option at all in my case, as the alterations done by the decorator effect the results of the latter executed methods.